# How to make a Package for any series? (Debian/Ubuntu launchpad PPA)

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packages, dpkg

I have a PPA on the launchpad for my little project called Qpdf Tools ([https://launchpad.net/~silash35/+archive/ubuntu/qpdftools](https://launchpad.net/%7Esilash35/+archive/ubuntu/qpdftools)).
In the process of making the source package, I wrote a Debian/changelog and inside the file, there is this line:

```
qpdftools (1.4-1) focal; urgency=low
```

But the package isn't just for the "Focal" version of Ubuntu, it is a universal package that can be installed on all dpkg distributions (Debian, Ubuntu, Linux Mint, etc). Although when I upload to my PPA, the package is only available for the Focal version of Ubuntu.

Is there a way to make a Package for all dpkg distributions? Change the "focal" in the changelog file for another word, like "all" or "universal".

Comment: Searched for __focal; urgency=low__ came up with alot of information, have you tried an online search, I used Bing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

After uploading the package, go to the launchpad website and access your PPA. Then click on "View package details" and then on "Copy packages".

Then select your package and in "Destination series:" select the other version of Ubuntu that you want to distribute your package. Check "Copy existing binaries" and finally click on the "Copy Packages" button.
Repeat the process for all other versions of Ubuntu.